# Import Pandas library using PythonNet in .Net

Tags: c#, .net, python.net

I'm trying to import Pandas library using PythonNet.
It always throws error "No Module names pandas".

```
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // Set the path to the Python DLL
            Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("PYTHONNET_PYDLL", @"C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311-32\python311.dll", EnvironmentVariableTarget.Process);

            // Initialize Python engine
            PythonEngine.Initialize();

            // Use the Python Global Interpreter Lock (GIL)
            using (Py.GIL())
            {
                var currentDirectory = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
                var pythonFilePath = Path.GetFullPath(Path.Combine(currentDirectory, @"..\..\..\"));
                dynamic sys = Py.Import("sys");
                sys.path.append(pythonFilePath);

                dynamic pd = Py.Import("pandas"); // Error at this line

                dynamic pythonScript = Py.Import("mypythonscript");
                // Call the 'say_hello' function from the Python module
                dynamic result = pythonScript.return_dataset();

                // Print the result
                Console.WriteLine(result);

                // Print the result
                Console.WriteLine(result);
            }

            // Shutdown Python engine
            PythonEngine.Shutdown();
        }
```

1. The official documentation does not mention much.
2. Tried chat gpt

Comment: I'm sure you've already evaluated it but, just in case you're not aware, there is a Pandas port for .NET.

Comment: Yes, but  I need to import library as I want to execute that directly on Python.